# Extract observations that match all possible permutations that match two columns

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame with 10,000 observations with two paired dataset. In another dataset, I have a few selected paired dataset.

```
test <- data.frame (iso1=c("A", "B", "C"))

data <- data.frame(hosp1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C", "A", "B"),
           hosp2=c("B", "c", "F", "C", "G", "A", "H", "A"),
                   dist= c(12,32,23,12,12,45,13))
```

Now, I want to extract all observations that forms a possible permutation of data from dataset "data" such as "A" & "B", "B" & "A", "A" & "C", "C" & "A", "B" & "C", "C" & "B" using the test data

I expect to get something like this

```
hosp1  hosp2   dist
A       B       12
B       C       23
C       A       12
B       A       13
```

Comment: Here is a method to get all combinations `expand.grid(test$iso1, test$iso1)`

Comment: @M.Viking Note that it's actually permutations.

Answer (score 3):

You can just test whether `test$iso1` appears in both `hosp1` and `hosp2`:

```
data[data$hosp1 %in% test$iso1 & data$hosp2 %in% test$iso1, ]
```

```
  hosp1 hosp2 dist
1     A     B   12
2     B     C   32
6     C     A   45
8     B     A   13
```

Note, I fixed an uncapitalized letter and a missing `dist` value in your example data.

Comment: It works as I wanted. Thank you for your help. I wanted to give you a thumbs up but i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we could just `filter` with `if_all` to find the if any of the elements in 'iso1' column are found in the 'hosp' columns

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(if_all(starts_with('hosp'), ~ .x %in% test$iso1))
```

-output

```
   hosp1 hosp2 dist
1     A     B   12
2     B     C   23
3     C     A   12
4     B     A   13
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(data, Reduce(`&`, lapply(data[1:2], `%in%`, test$iso1)))
  hosp1 hosp2 dist
1     A     B   12
2     B     C   23
6     C     A   12
8     B     A   13
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(hosp1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C", "A", "B"
), hosp2 = c("B", "C", "F", "C", "G", "A", "H", "A"), dist = c(12, 
23, 32, 12, 45, 12, 10, 13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thank you but no reputation to rate your answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral`.

Either displaying empty permutations as `NA`,

```
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(test$iso1, 2, FUN=\(x) {
  d <- data[with(data, hosp1 == x[1] & hosp2 == x[2]), 'dist']
  data.frame(hosp=t(x), dist=ifelse(is.null(d), NA_real_, d))
}) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#   hosp.1 hosp.2 dist
# 1      A      B   12
# 2      A      C   NA
# 3      B      A   13
# 4      B      C   32
# 5      C      A   45
# 6      C      B   NA
```

or getting rid of them.

```
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(test$iso1, 2, FUN=\(x) {
  d <- data[with(data, hosp1 == x[1] & hosp2 == x[2]), 'dist']
  if (!length(d) == 0) data.frame(hosp=t(x), dist=d) else NULL
}) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#   hosp.1 hosp.2 dist
# 1      A      B   12
# 2      B      A   13
# 3      B      C   32
# 4      C      A   45
```

---

*Data*

```
data <- structure(list(hosp1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C", "A", "B"
), hosp2 = c("B", "C", "F", "C", "G", "A", "H", "A"), dist = c(12, 
32, 23, 12, 12, 45, 13, 13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

test <- structure(list(iso1 = c("A", "B", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much but no reputation to rate your answer

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a concatenated permutation against concatenated hosp rows. Then asking... is "A B" in list ....

```
data <- data.frame(hosp1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "C", "A", "B"),
                   hosp2=c("B", "C", "F", "C", "G", "A", "H", "A"),
                   dist= c(12, 32,  23,   12,   12  ,45,  13, 13)) 
                   ### I added a missing value here

permu <-(expand.grid(test$iso1, test$iso1))

data[paste(data$hosp1, data$hosp2) %in% paste(permu$Var1, permu$Var2),]


  hosp1 hosp2 dist
1     A     B   12
2     B     C   32
6     C     A   45
8     B     A   13
```